# Where to render? Preprocess or template?

Tags: theming, performance

We are constantly improving our coding performance and we are monitoring every page load to optimize loading en rendering times in our websites.
Above statement in mind, I stumbled upon the question where should we render the renderable arrays?

If you render them in your preprocessor, the template keeps pretty neat since you're only printing variables.

Preprocessor:

```
function template_preprocess_node__faq(&$variables) {
    $node = node_load($variables['nid']);
    $node_style = node_view($node, $variables['view_mode']);

    $faq_sets = array(
      '#theme'  => 'my_module_faq_set',
      '#sets'   => $variables['field_faq_set'],
    );

    $variables['faq_image']   = render($node_style['field_faq_image']);
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="faq_image">
     <?php print $faq_image; ?>
</div>
```

However, I'm not sure it this is the proper/fastest/neatest way to preprocess and print variables.

Drupal isn't consisting in this matter either I guess... In the default `node.tpl.php` variables are rendered while in other default templates (like `html.php.php`), variables are just printed.

Does anyone have a rule and/or some tips and advices on how to tackle this issue the cleanest and fastest way?

Comment: This question is rather subjective. The general rule is that computing is done in the preprocess function and the rendering in the template file. It's not clear why you are using `node_view()` to render a field; fields are not rendered that way in a node template.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Then why is Drupal rendering in the `node.tpl.php` and printing in `html.tpl.php`? How would you tackle the `node_view()` issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Drupal isn't consisting in this matter either I guess... In the default node.tpl.php variables are rendered while in other default templates (like html.php.php), variables are just printed.

That's not quite right. If you look at [`template_preprocess_html()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) you can see that nothing is run through `render()`/`drupal_render()`. So quite simply the variables in html.tpl.php are printed rather than rendered because they don't *need* to be rendered. All the vars are already strings, and no render arrays were used to build the template.

Conversely, the node content in node.tpl.php *is* a render array. So any parts of it that need to be rendered have to be run through `render()` and not just printed.

I would be tempted to follow core's example of using `render()` in templates, not in preprocess functions, unless you have a specific reason to do it differently.

From a performance point of view the difference would surely be negligible, but profiling the code in the context of your site and hardware is the only way to be certain.